# Count Total Folder in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to read a folder that contains multiple inner folders, which have more than 100 xml files. I need to read all these xml files one by one. I am using asp.net c# . How can I achieve this.

For Example: `A` is my folder, containing `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`...`200` as sub-folders.
Now the folder `1` contains `a.xml`, `b.xml`, `c.xml` ... Similarly folder `2` contains `1.xml`, `2.xml`, `3.xml` ...
Now I need to read all these xml files one by one from each folder.

Comment: is that work for you ???

Comment: How many folder levels are there. If its unlimited you need to use recursion

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of parallel linq and do as below

```
  int count = 0;
    string[] files = null;
    try
    {
        files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You do not have permission to access one or more folders in this directory tree.");
        return;
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The specified directory {0} was not found.", path);
    }

    var fileContents = from file in files.AsParallel()
            let extension = Path.GetExtension(file)
            where extension == ".xml" 
            let text = File.ReadAllText(file)
            select new FileResult { Text = text , FileName = file }; //Or ReadAllBytes, ReadAllLines, etc.               

    try
    {
        foreach (var item in fileContents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(item.FileName) + ":" + item.Text.Length);
            count++;
        }
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        ae.Handle((ex) =>
            {
                if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                   return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
    }
```

Example takem from : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx